# OpenCV msec vs frame not matching up

Tags: java, opencv

I am working on a 119.88FPS, 1080P H.264 video file. I am doing CV to see whether or not the marker was visible in a given frame or not. I need to find the delta time between successive "positive" frames. The problem is that currentVC.get(Videoio.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC)does not agree with currentVC.get(Videoio.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAME) at all.
For instance, for the 24510th frame:

> openCV frame pos: 24510.416438356166
>
> openCV Timestamp: 149105.03333333333
>
> Total Frame Rate: 119.8801198804266
>
> Total Frame Count: 31775.8493150685
>
> Time stamp for last frameL: 193303

So

> 24510/31775 = 77 percent of vid has elapsed
>
> 149105/(193301) = 77 percent of vid has elapsed.

All is good so far, BUT

> 31775/120fps * 1000ms is about 4 and half minutes, and not 3:12 minute as >the final timestamp suggests.

Please let me know what the best way to go about timing my frames should be.

Comment: (31775.8493150685 * 1000)/ 193303 = 164.38363251 fps if I didnt make a mistake.

Comment: Hi Micka. Thanks for your help again! Does that mean the FPS information for the video is wrong?

Comment: either the video or the interpretation of opencv or the fps isnt constant. Did you record the video yourself?